# ¿Cómo hago para mostrar tantos inputs como indique el usuario?

Tags: python

Quiero que el código le pregunte al usuario "How many lines you want in your schedule?" y si el usuario le responde, por ejemplo, 6, entonces el codigo se encarga de hacerle 6 inputs, en donde el usuario responde el contenido de cada línea.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import getpass from pathlib import Path import time

def mainmenu():
    username = getpass.getuser()
    print ("Welcome %s\n\n" % username)
    print ("\t\t S C H E D U L E   H E L P E R")
    print ("\n\nPlease, choose an option")
    print ("\n1.")
    print ("\n2.")
    print ("\n3.")

def first_creator():
    print ("""
    This is the Schedule Creator option, here you can create schedules based 
    on the amount of lines you want it to be, and what type of file
    you want your schedule to be.\n 
    """)
    filename = input("Please input a filename or a path if the file is in another folder\n")
    filepath = Path(filename)
    if filepath.is_file():
        print ("ERROR: The file already exists, use option 2 to print it")
    else:
        print ("Creating file schedule file")
        createfile = open(filename, "w+")
        time.sleep(5)
        print ("File created, please input how many lines you want your schedule to be. (Max 10)\n")
        lines = input()
        # Idea: Se crean tantas lineas como el usuario haya elegido Y ES LUEGO cuando se le agrega el texto
        # Unas listas podrian funcionar
        # Se puede modificar la cantidad de valores que tiene una lista?
```

En la ultima parte de la función `first_creator()` yace mi duda.

Ejemplo de címo se vería en la consola:

```
How many lines you want in your schedule?
> 3
Please input line one:
> Hello
Please input line two:
> World
Please input line three:
> !
```

El problema es que no tengo ni idea de cómo hacer esto. Llevo horas pensando en una solución, pero mi mente novata no logra transcribir mis pensamientos a código.

Comment: Puedes crear una lista vacía `sched = []` antes de pedir al usuario cuántos elementos tendrá. Después hacer un bucle que se repita `lines` veces, y en cada iteración lea una cadena y la añada a la lista mediante `sched.append(cadena)`.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo harías con pseudocódigo? Una vez definido esto, escribirlo a código será más fácil

Answer (score 1):

Completando el código que publicaste quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
import getpass
import time
from pathlib import Path


def mainmenu():
    username = getpass.getuser()
    print("Welcome %s\n\n" % username)
    print("\t\t S C H E D U L E   H E L P E R")
    print("\n\nPlease, choose an option")
    print("\n1.")
    print("\n2.")
    print("\n3.")


def first_creator():
    print("""
    This is the Schedule Creator option, here you can create schedules based 
    on the amount of lines you want it to be, and what type of file
    you want your schedule to be.\n 
    """)
    filename = input(
        "Please input a filename or a path if the file is in another folder\n")
    filepath = Path(filename)
    if filepath.is_file():
        print("ERROR: The file already exists, use option 2 to print it")
    else:
        print("Creating file schedule file")
        createfile = open(filename, "w+")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("File created, please input how many lines you want your schedule to be. (Max 10)\n")

        # Conversión de str a int (De Cadena a Numero Entero)
        lines = int(input())
        # Definimos una Lista Vacia donde se guardaran las entradas del usuario
        tasks = []

        # Definimos un diccionario para la relacion numero -> texto en ingles
        numbers_letter = {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three",
            4: "four",
            5: "five",
            6: "six",
            7: "seven",
            8: "eight",
            9: "nine",
            10: "ten"
        }
        # Iteramos para solicitar las entradas
        # la funcion range crea una secuencia, en este caso del 0 a (<lines>-1)
        for i in range(lines):
            """
            Cada Entrada (funcion input) se agrega a la lista <tasks>
            Con la funcion format 'das formato' a la cadena de salida
            En este caso reemplazara {} por lo que retorne <number_letter> en la
            posicion de (i+1)
            """
            tasks.append(
                input("Please input line {}:\n".format(numbers_letter[(i+1)]))
            )


# Ejecutamos las funciones
mainmenu()
first_creator()
```

Cabe mencionar que dicho código primero genera un archivo y luego te solicita el número de entradas, posiblemente para que al final todas las entradas puedan guardarse en el archivo creado.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar un ciclo. Primero se le pide al usuario la cantidad de líneas y, una vez obtenida la respuesta, se utiliza un while o un for para pedir la cantidad de líneas. Opcionalmente, se puede usar una lista para guardar las líneas que se ingresan.

```
lines_number = int(input("How many lines you want in your schedule?\n"))

lines = []

for number in range(lines_number):
    new_line = input("Please input line " + str(number + 1) + ":\n")
    lines.append(new_line)
```